# Can I hand over a Bahn 100 card?

Tags: trains, germany, deutsche-bahn

One of my friends is leaving from Germany, having a bahn 100 card. So he wants to hand over the card that will be expired at the middle of next year to me. 
So is it possible to change the owner of the card from him to me? if it's possible how to do that?

Comment: As answered, this is not possible. However, your friend should contact the bahn.comfort service and ask nicely if it is possible to return the card and get a refund of a part of the money for the remaining months. If he has proof that he will leave Germany, they might do this out of goodwill.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible. Someone asked this at [Deutsche Bahn support community](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1255294-bahncard-100-altem-neuen-mitarbeiter-ubertragen)
 and their answer was

> Hallo Frager1234, auch eine Umschreibung der BahnCard 100 ist nicht möglich. /an

*Hi Frager1234, it's not possible to have a BahnCard 100 re-issued to another person.*

Comment: Here is [a community question](https://community.bahn.de/questions/1446293-bc-25-umzug-ins-ausland-bc-25-andere-person-uberschreiben-lassen "BC 25 und Umzug ins Ausland - kann ich die BC 25 auf eine andere Person überschreiben lassen?") about the case of leaving Germany (it’s sometimes possible to cancel contracts in such a case), but the the answer (confirmed by the Bahn) is the same: not possible.

Answer (score 1):

From the website of the Deutsche Bahn:

> 2.8
>   Übertragbarkeit
>
> Die Fahrkarte ist nur dann übertragbar, wenn sie nicht auf den Namen lautet und die Fahrt - bei Fahrkarten für Hin-
>   und Rückfahrt die Hinfahrt - noch nicht angetreten ist. Reisende mit 
>   auf den Namen lautenden Fahrkarten sind
>   verpflichtet, im Rahmen der Fahrkartenkontrolle
>   auf Aufforderung ihre Identität durch einen amtlichen Lichtbildausweis nachzuweisen.

In English: tickets (of all sorts) can only be given to others if they're not specifically assigned to a person. The Bahn Card 100 contains the name of the owner and thus can't be transfered.

However you could try to get a new card by convincing the Deutsche Bahn that your friend has changed his name and address to yours. But I have no idea if that would work.

Comment: Addition: in any case I would call the Deutsche Bahn and ask directly. If there's an other way, they'll know ;-)

Comment: You are right that BahnCards can't be transferred to another person. They are however discount cards and not *tickets* and the text you are quoting do not apply to BahnCards.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Bahncards 25 and 50 are only discount cards, however with a Bahncard 100 you can use basically every train in Germany without buying a separate ticket, so the Bahncard 100 itself counts as the ticket

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo according to TfV 600 C1, general rules (which include TfV 600 A2.8) also apply to Bahn Cards as long as TfV 600 C2 and follwing don't state otherwise.

Comment: "However you could try to get a new card by convincing the Deutsche Bahn that your friend has changed his name and address to yours. But I have no idea if that would work." - if you're suggesting this it's a bit dangerous if you don't also find out whether or not it's illegal, and if it is, what penalties it carries. In the UK, this would be fraud, and so is a pretty big deal.

Comment: @NicolasB It is obvious from TfV A2ff, especially 2.1.2, 2.3, 2.4.2, 2.5.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 that the terms and conditions for a ticket *(Fahrkarte)* do not apply to a BahnCard 100. Changes and refunds of a BahnCard are regulated in TfV C3.6, relevant in this case is section 3.6.4: *In any other case, a change or refund of the BahnCard 100 is not possible.*